# AskUbuntu background flicker

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

When scrolling a page on askubuntu, the background dots flicker visually.
It is a minor thing but the fix is so simple, just to set:

*background-attachment: fixed*

When i do it manually in the browser it looks perfect.

Why is background not *fixed* on askubuntu?

Comment: Can't say that I notice any flickering. Could you create a video or gif to demonstrate?

Comment: @Seth maybe flicker isn't the right word, but the dots move in the background when you scroll and it is a pretty unpleasant effect. It's been bugging me for ages too. Try looking at the left hand menu while scrolling.